# Laravel App kept logging users out

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Recently, my Laravel site keep logging me out a very short time - `maybe` in about 30 seconds ish ...

---

What should I check or look into ? How do I debug this ?

---

in `config/session.php`

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */
```

I have `'lifetime' => 2,`, should I increase it ?

What else that could lead the app to log-out ?

Comment: check in console to see error if any and laravel storage log fil

Comment: Google Chrome Console ?

Comment: lifetime => 2 means two minutes sessoin lfetime, therefore a logout every 2 minutes - so yes - increase it :)

Answer (score 0):

It says there in the comments **"specify the number of minutes that you wish the session to be allowed to remain idle before it expires"**.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,
```

The above expires in two hours, yours expires in 2 minutes.